# Node.js Express link to JavaScript file from ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on Nodejs/Express project. My view is built using ejs file. I have several JavaScript functions that I am using. If I place them inside script tag within ejs file everything works fine. However, if I place those functions into my.js file and try to reference it from ejs it doesn't work. in my app.js i have:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

the my.js file is placed in /public/js/my.js
I am using:

```
<script src='/js/drag_drop.js'></script>
```

Any guidance is breatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you facing problem in creating the views?

Comment: @Alexander. No the functions are not called if placed in separate file.

Comment: you have to export them in my.js file and then require them in file you wish to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/), or [grunt.js](https://gruntjs.com/). These frameworks are essentially a build system, meaning you can grab all the Javascript files and concatenate into one file to be loaded form index.html. Since your approaching with ejs, look into modules such as this [gulp-ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ejs) and etc.

Typically you'd want your gulp/grunt/ whatever build framework you choose, to put in

```
'public/js/script.js'
```

Then in index.html you would load it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was putting my reference before body in ejs files. As soon as I moved it to the bottom everything is working.